# How to restrict user to not input decimal values in Angular?

Tags: regex, angular

I want to restrict user to not input decimal values & also not less than hundred.
If user enters value less than 100 an error message display says "Min. value is 100" &
If user enters value in decimal(e.g 138.01) an error message display says "Decimal values are not allowed".
Please help!!!

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afjtjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply by giving min length(3) and pattern
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4fucrf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern="^[0-9]+([0-9]{0,0})?$" step="1"`.

This works on your Stackbliz example

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Enter Coins to Withdraw</label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="withdraw_coins" placeholder="min. 100" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.withdraw_coins.errors }" pattern="^[0-9]+([0-9]{0,0})?$" step="1">
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.withdraw_coins.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.withdraw_coins.errors.required">Withdraw Coins is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.withdraw_coins.errors.min">
               Number should be greater than 100.
             </div>
             <div *ngIf="f.withdraw_coins.errors?.pattern">
                Decimal values are not allowed
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in Angular [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators). You can combine the validators to help with your problem. Specifically the `min` and `pattern` methods should solve your issue.

Note: when using more than one validator, you'll need to put the validators in a nested array.

```
// app.component.ts

this.withdrawCoinsForm = this.fb.group({
    withdraw_coins: ['', [
        Validators.required, 
        Validators.min(100),
        Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')]
    ]
});

// app.component.html

<label>Enter Coins to Withdraw</label>
<input class="form-control" 
      formControlName="withdraw_coins" 
      placeholder="min. 100" 
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.withdraw_coins.errors }">
<div *ngIf="f.withdraw_coins.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.withdraw_coins.errors.min">
        Must be a min of 100!
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="f.withdraw_coins.errors.pattern">
        Must not have a decimal!
    </div>
</div>
```